# Automatically Run Access Query w/ date range parameters

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Trying to automatically run an access query in excel and update the date criteria based on user input. Not sure how to code in vba a parameter for entering the between date and getting the query to post automatically in excel under a header column in a2.

Access Query:
'''SELECT hosp_chg.HOSP_ACCT_ID, hosp_chg.SVC_DATE, hosp_chg.POST_DATE, [hosp_chg.POST_DATE]-
[hosp_chg.SVC_DATE] AS [Lag Days], hosp_chg.ACCT_CLASS_ID, acct_class_master.TITLE, "" AS
[Inpatient or Outpatient], hosp_chg.REVENUE_CODE_ID, hosp_chg.COST_CENTER_ID,
cost_center_master.COST_CENTER_CODE, cost_center_master.COST_CENTER_NAME, "" AS [WDY Cost
Center Mapping], hosp_chg.DEPT_ID, department_master.DEPT_NAME, hosp_chg.PROC_ID,
procedure_master.PROC_CODE, procedure_master.PROC_NAME, hosp_chg.ORIG_AMT, hosp_chg.QUANTITY,
hosp_chg.LATE_CHG_YN, user_master.USER_ID, user_master.USER_NAME,
user_master.DEFAULT_USERROLE, "" AS [Include/Exclude in Reporting],
hosp_chg.REVERSE_ORIG_TRAN_ID, hosp_chg.REPOST_ORIG_TRAN_ID,
hosp_chg.LATE_CHG_CRED_ORIG_TRAN_ID, hosp_chg.LATE_CHG_CORRECT_ORIG_TRAN_ID
FROM acct_class_master INNER JOIN ((((hosp_chg INNER JOIN cost_center_master ON
hosp_chg.COST_CENTER_ID = cost_center_master.COST_CENTER_ID) INNER JOIN department_master ON
hosp_chg.DEPT_ID = department_master.DEPT_ID) INNER JOIN procedure_master ON hosp_chg.PROC_ID
= procedure_master.PROC_ID) INNER JOIN user_master ON hosp_chg.USER_ID = user_master.USER_ID)
ON acct_class_master.ID = hosp_chg.ACCT_CLASS_ID
GROUP BY hosp_chg.HOSP_ACCT_ID, hosp_chg.SVC_DATE, hosp_chg.POST_DATE, [hosp_chg.POST_DATE]-
[hosp_chg.SVC_DATE], hosp_chg.ACCT_CLASS_ID, acct_class_master.TITLE,
hosp_chg.REVENUE_CODE_ID, hosp_chg.COST_CENTER_ID, cost_center_master.COST_CENTER_CODE,
cost_center_master.COST_CENTER_NAME, hosp_chg.DEPT_ID, department_master.DEPT_NAME,
hosp_chg.PROC_ID, procedure_master.PROC_CODE, procedure_master.PROC_NAME, hosp_chg.ORIG_AMT,
hosp_chg.QUANTITY, hosp_chg.LATE_CHG_YN, user_master.USER_ID, user_master.USER_NAME,
user_master.DEFAULT_USERROLE, "", hosp_chg.REVERSE_ORIG_TRAN_ID, hosp_chg.REPOST_ORIG_TRAN_ID,
hosp_chg.LATE_CHG_CRED_ORIG_TRAN_ID, hosp_chg.LATE_CHG_CORRECT_ORIG_TRAN_ID, ""
HAVING (((hosp_chg.POST_DATE) **Between [Enter the beginning date MM/DD/YY] And [Enter the
ending date MM/DD/YY])** AND ((hosp_chg.ORIG_AMT)>0) AND ((hosp_chg.LATE_CHG_YN)="Y") AND
((hosp_chg.REVERSE_ORIG_TRAN_ID) Is Null) AND ((hosp_chg.REPOST_ORIG_TRAN_ID) Is Null) AND
((hosp_chg.LATE_CHG_CRED_ORIG_TRAN_ID) Is Null) AND ((hosp_chg.LATE_CHG_CORRECT_ORIG_TRAN_ID)
Is Null))
ORDER BY hosp_chg.REVENUE_CODE_ID;'''

'

My error is on the parameters but i do not know how to fix any help would be greatly appreciated. THANKS IN ADVANCE!!

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with mysql so removed the tag.

Comment: Make [Enter the X Date] a direct reference of two cells. `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("X1").Value` and `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Y1").Value` and just enter the dates on those cells. Then put the query into a Recordset object. After that you paste using copyfromrecordset into A2: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PasteSheet").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset recordsetobject` . If nothing from before makes sense then readup on Access Recordset VBA Object in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Ricardo A has given you a good answer.  Here's the VBA code to do what he suggests:

1. Have the user enter the beginning and ending dates in two cells of the workbook, perhaps cells X1 and Y1
2. Use the data from those cells to put the values in the query as follows (assuming your query is a variable named SQL):

   ```
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "[Enter the beginning date MM/DD/YY]", "#" & range("X1").text & "#")
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "[Enter the ending date MM/DD/YY]", "#" & range("Y1").text & "#")
   ```

That will put the values into your query as date literals.

Comment: would it be like this Sub LateCharges()
Dim MyDatabase As DAO.Database
Dim MyQueryDef As DAO.QueryDef
Dim MyRecordset As DAO.Recordset
Set MyDatabase = DBEngine.OpenDatabase _
("P:\Patient Accounts\Vargas, Ashley\Onboarding\KIDS\KIDS Database.accdb")
Set MyQueryDef = MyDatabase.QueryDefs("Late Charges")
Sql = Replace("POST_DATE", "[Enter the beginning date MM/DD/YY]", "#" & Range("X1").Text & "#")
Sql = Replace("POST_DATE", "[Enter the ending date MM/DD/YY]", "#" & Range("Y1").Text & "#")
Set MyRecordset MyQueryDef.OpenRecordset()ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset MyRecordset

Comment: This kind of follow-up is better done in a chat room.  Post your code again in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243250/excel-and-access-with-vba and I'll take a look